# Differential equation with initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation $$y'= \frac{1}{ty}$$ where $y(1)=2$. 
I have no idea how to solve this, and any help would be great!

Comment: Is your ode $ y'= \frac{y}{t} $?

Comment: Do you know about separable equations?

Comment: Is this a hmoework problem?

Comment: this is on a practice

Comment: @PatrickSlackman: See the edit to your post. Is this the right equation?

Comment: the equation is correct. y'= 1/ty where y(1)=2. it is all correct

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  For the future, please keep in mind that showing any type of attempt you have performed will help us know how to help you best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dt}&=\frac{1}{ty} \\
y \, dy &= \frac{dt}{t} & \text{separate the variables}\\
\int y \, dy &= \int \frac{dt}{t} \\
\frac{y^2}{2}&=\ln|t|+C &\text{integrate both sides} \\
y(t)&=\pm \sqrt{2\ln|t|+C} & \text{solve for $y=y(t)$}
\end{align}
Applying $y(1)=2$, we get
\begin{align}2&=\pm\sqrt{2\ln|1|+C} \\
4&=2\ln|1|+C & \text{square both sides} \\
4&=2\cdot0+C & \text{because } \ln|1|=0 \\
4&=C
\end{align}
Thus, $\boxed{y= \sqrt{2\ln|t|+4}}$

Comment: How did $\frac{1}{t}$ become $t$?

Comment: I am very sorry, for some reason it changed what I typed it is not 1/t. the 1 is being divided by ty

Comment: @PatrickSlackman I was the one who edited your post and misinterpreted your equation. I reverted that edit I made and modified my answer accordingly. I hope this helps!

Comment: @Glacier Since $y(1) = 2 > 0$, you need drop the negative square root.

Comment: @Braindead thanks for catching that

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use separation of variables technique

$$ {yy'} = \frac{1}{t}  $$

Comment: yes I know of the separation of variables but I am not sure what to do after I get the y's together